# windows uses long int as if in a 32-bit machine while in 64-bit

Tags: c++, c, 64-bit, overflow, long-integer

I'm using 10 64-bit.
when running the following code for example, I get an overflow and a negative number is printed, while on a linux 64-machine I get the actual number printed:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    long int a = 3845354610;
    printf("Hello, World!%ld\n", a);
    scanf("%ld", &a);
    return 0;
}
```

The output on windows is:

```
Hello, World!-449612686
```

and on linux it's the right output.

I tried using the `--build-64bit` flag in the CMake options in CLion. I'm using `mingw-64 (D:\MinGW\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64`).

I tried using the cmd to compile:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wvla -std=c99 main.c -o ma.exe
```

but the output was the same. How can this be fixed?

Comment: @4386427 although this is a simple example, in places where I need to recieve this number as an input, I won't be able to place that "L" at the end.

Comment: @4386427 yes, that was the original problem, and it doesn't work

Comment: `3845354610` does not fit in a signed 32-bit integer.

Comment: And what is `printf("%zu\n", sizeof(long int));`

Comment: @4386427 it gives `4`

Comment: @WeatherVane and the question remains: why does a 64bit machine use 32bit long, although the internet says it should be 64

Comment: @ArielYael well, that's it then.... 4x8 = 32 bits can't store 3845354610

Comment: Because it can? Is `int` also still 32 bits?

Comment: @ArielYael Where does " the internet says it should be 64" ?

Comment: @WeatherVane `printf ("%d %d", sizeof(long), sizeof(int));` gives me `4` for both of them

Comment: MS treats the 64-bits as applying to *pointers*. That's the difference.

Comment: @WeatherVane I'm not sure I follow

Comment: @4386427 about your question please see the comments on eerorika's answer

Comment: The 32-bit MSVC uses 32-bit pointer, the 64-bit MSVC used 64-bit pointers (same with GCC). But MSVC stays with 32-bit `int ` and `long`. It is allowed to.

Comment: If you are talking about https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/limits.h then you are not reading the table correct. It says that `long int` must be at least 32 bits. It is **NOT** saying 64 bits.

Comment: @ArielYael **ANSI standard minimum** is the rigth most column. My guess is that you look at **Typical value**

Comment: For these reasons I never use `long`. I have never had any need for it. But on a 16-bit embedded system, you can get the 16, 32, and 64-bit integers. In recent times `int32_t` and `int64_t` have been used if you need a definite size.

Comment: Anyway... if the size of an integer is important use `intN_t`

Comment: @WeatherVane OK. Maybe I didn't understand what you mean by `But on a 16-bit embedded system, you can get the 16, 32, and 64-bit integers.` I thought you were referring to the size of `long`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can this be fixed?

By using `long long` or `std::int64_t`. `long` is required / guaranteed to be at least 32 bits, and that's the size of `long` on (64 bit) windows.

Comment: why then [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/limits.h) site states that on 64-bit the size should be much larger?

Comment: @ArielYael It doesn't state such thing. It says: `LONG_MAX - ANSI standard maximum magnitude value - ≥+2,147,483,647` What is unclear about that?

Comment: @ArielYael use the table here and look https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types _"Win64 API - LLP64 or 4/4/8 (int and long are 32-bit, pointer is 64-bit)_"

Comment: what do they mean by LONG_MAX -> 64 bit compiler ->+9,223,372,036,854,775,807
 then?

Comment: @ArielYael Read the title of the column: "**typical** value". "Typical" doesn't mean "always" or "guaranteed" or "required". The author of that page evidently doesn't consider 64 bit Window's implementation typical.

Comment: @eerorika Ok, in that case, I would like to know how to change it to be that

Comment: @ArielYael different platforms have different sizes - MS-Windows need to remain backward compatible with the 32-bit API so kept  `long` as 32-bits.

Comment: @ArielYael You cannot choose what size `long` is in your language implementation. You could choose to use a language implementation where `long` is 64 bit by not using windows. But it's generally better to not rely on `long` having a particular size allowing your program to be portable.

Comment: @RichardCritten I understand, thank you

Comment: To avoid this type of problem in future, consider adding asserts to your code that confirm your assumptions about the size of your data types.